# Google App Script - send email using only 1 row of data per email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was able to build a script to send an email if a new row of data is inputted into google sheets and if Merge Status isn't "pass". However, the script sends out emails with multiple rows of data in one email that isn't "pass". How can I adjust the script to just use one row of data per email? (1 row of data = 1 email) Thanks in advance!

Google Sheets

```
 function sendEmail() {

 var ActiveSheet = 
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Pass");

 var StartRow = 2;

 var RowRange = ActiveSheet.getLastRow() - StartRow + 1;

 var WholeRange = ActiveSheet.getRange(StartRow,1,RowRange,10);

 var AllValues = WholeRange.getValues();

 var message = "";

 for (var i=0;i<AllValues.length;i++) 

 {

 var CurrentRow = AllValues[i];

 var EmailSent = CurrentRow[9];

 if (EmailSent!="pass")

 {
 
   message +=
      "<p><b>Name: </b>" + CurrentRow[2] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Date: </b>" + CurrentRow[2] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Referral Link: </b>" + CurrentRow[8] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Signup Link: </b>" + CurrentRow[8] + "</p><br><br>";
   
 var setRow = i + StartRow;

 ActiveSheet.getRange(setRow, 10).setValue("pass");

 var SendTo = CurrentRow[4] ;

 var Subject = "[Action Required] - Virtual Interview Signup";

 var CC = CurrentRow[7] ;

 var ReplyTo = CurrentRow [7] ;

 //send the actual email  
 MailApp.sendEmail({

      to: SendTo,

      cc: CC,

      subject: Subject,

      replyto: ReplyTo,

      htmlBody: message,

     });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

on a successful mail sent inside your `if()` condition you can use `break;` which will break the flow go out of loop.

Comment: After adding 'break;' - it doesn't continuously send out emails for each row that doesn't satisfy the if() and it just stops at the next row that doesn't qualify if (). Also, the emails are capturing all rows of data up to the latest row of if()  - ex: email for row 7 will contain data from 1st to 7th row.  Hoping I can send out emails for each of the row that doesn't satisfy the if() criteria with only the data from that row.

Comment: i'm unable to understand your problem clearly, can you please elaborate in detail what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

The "message" variable must be declared inside the for loop. Now you combine the new message with the old one in each iteration.

If you want to learn more, read about the scope of variables.